# Copying variables from userland

Tags: c, linux, kernel, kernel-module

I feel like this question has been answered but no implementation I've found from googling it has offered the protection I need.

I am working with linux 3.2.2.

I wish to copy variables from user space to kernal space as safely as possible. This includes a struct pointer, and a null terminated string. How could i ensure my struct pointer is valid? (access_ok on (void*) -1 does not catch it) I want it to be basically idiot proof...

For the null terminated string i don't know the length and some of the functions that copy these null terminated strings want a size.

Comment: If you are in kernel you know which adresses are valid (you have access to all translation tables from the MMU) from there you can check if the given adress is at least valid for that application. If the struct itself contains only plausible data is much harder to guarantee if you don't know any constraints about the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: So the best solution I found was actually the code I was using just put an and instead of an or.

check if ptr is null first of all.
then

```
access_ok(VERIFY_READ/WRITE,ptr,structsize)
```

if this passes our usr ptr or struct is within the user address space. 
finally use

```
int copy_from_user(void* dest, void* src,size_t len)
```

and make sure destPtr points to a space in kernel thats size is obviously >= structsize.
Even now there is no guarantee that the data in the structure is useful, or what you want at all. It just is raw data that will not cause a kernel panic. So now you can check each member of the struct for valid data. there is some more useful information on this

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-kernel-memory-access/

Answer (score 0):

Using a [ioctl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl) we should able to copy structures to kernel space. I've been successful copy a variable to kernel using a dummy ioctl created.